# Error exporting SQL database to XML or CSV C#

Tags: c#, sql, xml, csv, frameworks

Here's my problem, I've tried this code to export an SQL Database to XML :

```
try
{
    // Connect to database.
    connect.Open();
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    // Confirm unsuccessful connection and stop program execution.
    Console.WriteLine("Erreur de connection à la BDD.");
    System.Environment.Exit(0);
}

// Export path and file.
string exportPath = "C:\\sauvegardes\\";
string exportXml = "personexport.xml";

// Check to see if the file path exists.
if (Directory.Exists(exportPath))
{
    try
    {
        // Query text.
        string sqlText =
                "SELECT * " +
                "FROM personnel " +
                "ORDER BY ID_Personnel";

        // Query text incorporated into SQL command.
        SqlCommand sqlSelect = new SqlCommand(sqlText, connect);

        // Execute SQL and place data in a reader object.
        SqlDataReader reader = sqlSelect.ExecuteReader();

        // If data has been returned, do the export.
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            // Create the XML file.
            using (XmlTextWriter writer =
                new XmlTextWriter(exportPath + exportXml, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                // Set the formatting for the document.
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                writer.Indentation = 4;

                // Add the declaration for the document.
                writer.WriteStartDocument();

                // Open the root element.
                writer.WriteStartElement("people");

                // Process the rows of data.
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Open the person element.
                    writer.WriteStartElement("personnel");

                    // Add the person details.
                    writer.WriteElementString("ID_Personnel", reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    writer.WriteElementString("Prenom", reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
                    writer.WriteElementString("Nom", reader.GetValue(2).ToString());
                    writer.WriteElementString("Telephone", reader.GetValue(3).ToString());
                    writer.WriteElementString("Mail", reader.GetValue(4).ToString());

                    // Close the person element.
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }

                // Close the root element.
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                // Close the XML document.
                writer.WriteEndDocument();

                // Flush the internal buffer.
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Message stating no data to export.
            Console.WriteLine("There is no data to export.");
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        // Message stating export successful.
        Console.WriteLine("Data export successful.");
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        // Message stating export unsuccessful.
        Console.WriteLine("Data export unsuccessful.");
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the database connection.
        connect.Close();
    }

}
else
{

    // Display a message stating file path does not exist.
    Console.WriteLine("File path does not exist.");
}
```

Everything seems good, I've got no error but when the code finished to run, nothing happened, the file isn't created at all.

I've tried to figure out what happenned but I couldn't find out.
The path is good but it doesn't work, it's been 1 day I've been stuck on it.

Comment: The title and what you describe are misleading and tells different thing. In the title you state **Error ..** but then you say **I've got no error**. May you describe better what's the actual behavior ? Is there an error or there isn't?

Comment: I Have one suggestion that will solve the issue by doing a complete change on the method. Use an ORM to select your data. Linq2sql/dapper anything . It will need one conextion string and few click. Then you will have a `List<Personnel>`. And you can ask C# to serialize that into a XML with 3 lines of codes. The same thing if you need a CSV you can use CSV helper and write that file in 1 line of code.

Comment: The whole thing will boil to 10 lines max without consolewrite and try catch.

Comment: for debuging I will first remove the Xml part and simply print to the console. You will know if that the issue. If it is you can drop the whole DB part and start with a simple Bogus List of object and try to serialize that into XML. basically you will build and [MRE]

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to do that ?

Comment: Quelle partie? J'ai évoqué 5-6 trucs?

Comment: Are you sure the `personnel` table has data in it?